# Spring Security OAuth - how to enable private or public access token accessing different resources?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have two end-points.

`/foo` - is a internal (semi-private) endpoint. It is allowed only for the clients configured. (No userName and credentials are needed; but clientID is sufficient)

`/greetings` - is a private endpoint. It is allowed only for clients and user configured. (both clientID and username and password is required)

Here is the configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
            ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            // @formatter:off
            resources
                .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/users").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/greeting").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/foo").authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
            AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            endpoints
                .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients
                .inMemory()
                    .withClient("clientapp")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token","authorization_code")
                        .authorities("USER","ROLE_CLIENT")
                        .scopes("read", "write")
                        .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                        .secret("123456")
                        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(600);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
            return tokenServices;
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception
        {
           oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the controller

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s! your password is %s";

    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, user.getName(),user.getPassword()));
    }

    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    public String foo(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        System.out.println(user==null);
        return "you are permitted here";
    }

}
```

I am NOT able to access `http://localhost:9001/foo` without any token.
so when I try to get access token using the curl below ( note I do not pass username and password, only client_id and client_secret is passed)

c`url -X POST -vu clientapp:123456 http://localhost:9001/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=123456&client_id=clientapp"`

I get this error

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Bad credentials"}
```

something is wrong with my configuration. I am a beginner using Spring security OAuth. would appreciate any help here.

thanks

Comment: Did you review fue line .antMatchers("/foo").authenticated(); it seems tour configuration is requesting authentication flor /foo

Comment: As I mentioned, I want /`foo` to be accessible only by client. Not public. But  the client can access without supplying username and password. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing wrong `grant_type`...

```
curl -X POST -vu clientapp:123456 http://localhost:9001/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=read%20write&client_secret=123456&client_id=clientapp"
```

Also as far as I remember you shouldn't  duplicate `client_id` and `client_secret` in the header and body of request.. Only header should be enough